# Financial and/or credit risk management

Tags: credit, risk, risk-management

A portfolio consists of two (long) assets £100 million each. The probability of default over the next year is 10% for the first asset, 20% for the second asset, and the joint probability of default is 3%.

Estimate the expected loss on this portfolio due to credit defaults over the next year assuming 40% recovery rate for both assets.

1)£19 million

2)£22 million

3)£30 million

4)None of the above

Which is correct answer?

My attempted answer:

Computation of weighted average default probability =
£100,000,000 × 0.1 × 0.6 + £100,000,000 × 0.2 × 0.6 + £200,000,000 × 0.03 × 0.6 = £21,600,000

So my answer is £22,000,000 approx.

Answer provided is given below:

[image: Credit risk management]

Additional helpful information:

[image: CRM1]

[image: CRM2]
[image: CRM3]

Comment: Please show some effort on what exactly you tried.

Comment: Did your text book discuss credit defaults and recovery rates?

Comment: This is not a -personal finance question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computation of expected loss on this portfolio due to credit defaults over the next year assuming 40% recovery rate for both assets:

**£100 million × 0.6 × 0.07 + £100 million × 0.6 × 0.17 + £200 million × 0.6 × 0.03 = £18 million** which is very close to £19 million, hence the answer to this question is £19 million